# Foursquare API Disconnect User

Tags: oauth-2.0, foursquare

I have users who have authorized foursquare to connect to my app but then have subsequently deleted their account on my app.   I use the foursquare real time push api and foursquare keeps pushing checkins of users who no longer use my app.  Right now I just ignore them, but I'd like to make an API call to disconnect these users from my app so I stop recieving their pushes.  I can't find anything on that in the docs.   Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foursquare doesn't provide a way to programmatically disconnect users. There are security implications here, and the only way a Foursquare user should be able to disconnect any of their apps is after they have logged in with their credentials on foursquare.com.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that there are worse security implications in not having a way to do this, especially with the real-time (push) API.  Most users are not savvy enough to go into Foursquare.com to remove an app, especially since apps make the connection pretty seamlessly.  Once someone deletes an app, having the app's server continue to get push messages every time that user checks-in is a privacy issue.